# Loopback 3.8 and Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs, azure-cosmosdb

We have a Loopback v3.8 application using MongoDB connector v3.1
It works fine in the environments running native MongoDB but now we would like to deploy to Azure and use Cosmos DB, which in theory should support all the native MongoDB commands.

The problem we're having is that PATCH operations (which I believe are mapped to Model.updateAttributes by Loopback) are not working.
This is the error we get:

> Could not update Client.  { Error: No Client found for id
>   592cc132a31109354c45d1d8 }

Loopback debug strings:

```
loopback:connector:mongodb updateAttributes +7ms Client 592cc132a31109354c45d1d8 { '$set': { loginDate:2017-06-02T12:30:18.201Z } }
loopback:connector:mongodb MongoDB: model=Client command=findAndModify +2ms [ { _id: 592cc132a31109354c45d1d8 },
[ [ '_id', 'asc' ] ],
{ '$set': { loginDate: 2017-06-02T12:30:18.201Z } },
{}, [Function] ]
loopback:connector:mongodb Result:  +399ms { _t: 'FindAndModifyResponse', ok: 1, value: null, lastErrorObject: { n: 1, updatedExisting: false, value: null } }
loopback:connector:mongodb updateAttributes.callback +4ms Client 592cc132a31109354c45d1d8 null { _t: 'FindAndModifyResponse', ok: 1,
value: null,
lastErrorObject: { n: 1, updatedExisting: false, value: null } }
```

If we do a GET for that Client, using its Id, we get the correct response, so the Client document is there.

Can the Loopback MongoDB connector used for Cosmos DB?
Are we missing something that requires Loopback to work correctly with Cosmos DB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the underlying base for cosmosdb is no longer MongoDB, it simply allows you to access is using a familiar API. The MongoDB connector is not intended for use with Cosmos DB, I personally have been looking for a solution for my own use and came across the NPM package `loopback-connector-cosmosdb` which worked for some simple applications but is ***completely unsupported*** by it's developer and loopback.